# Custom event handling system c++

Tags: c++, event-handling, c++17, function-pointers, std-function

I'm working on the library which also contains an event-handling module. I have a working proof of concept, but I'm worried about the performance of std::function. Thing is, events like MouseMove is going to occur very often. Is it even relevant here? Should I replace it with the function pointer or make any other change? Thank you.

```
class Event
{
    EventType type_;
public:
    enum class EventType { MouseMove, /* etc */ };
    Event(EventType type) : type_{type} {}
    EventType Type() const { return type_ };
};
class MouseMoveEvent : public Event
{
    int x_; // x point
    int y_; // y point
public:
    MouseMoveEvent(int x, int y) : Event(EventType::MouseMove), x_{x}, y_{y} {}
};

// SomeSystemClass is some native system class which can receive various system events
class Receiver : public SomeSystemClass
{
    // can contain handlers for various events of different receivers
    std::function<bool(Receiver*, Event*)> event_procedure_;

    // this is called by the system - return value decides if system should process this event
    bool OnMouseMove(int x, int y) override
    {
        if (event_procedure_)
        {
            MouseMoveEvent me(x, y);
            return event_procedure_(this, &me);
        }

        return false; // event was not processed -> continue to process by the system
    }

public:
    template <typename F>
    void SetEventProcedure(F&& event_proc)
    {
        event_proc_ = std::forward<F>(event_proc);
    }

    const std::function<bool(BaseGUIObject*, Event*)>& EventProcedure() const
    {
        return event_procedure_;
    }
};

// ---------------------------------------------
// USER CODE
int main()
{
    Receiver r;
    r.SetEventProcedure([](Receiver* r, Event* e)
    {
        switch (e->Type())
        {
            case Event::EventType::MouseMove:
                // do something
                return true; // event was processed by user -> stop system processing
            default:
                ; // unknown event
        }
        return false; // system processing
    });

}
```

Comment: _"I'm worried about the performance of std::function"_ -- So have you run any benchmarks?

Comment: I was about to. I'm only wondering if anybody has any experience doing something like this and is willing to share some knowledge.

Comment: Nobody else really knows the constraints of your system. I can, however, tell you that "MouseMove" is unlikely to occur much more than 60 times per second, and that's _nothing_ on modern hardware.